# solr field search on nested table fields OK, but default search not showing

Tags: solr

I have installed solr 4.5 (with Tomcat 7.0.37  container) and imported data from MySQL database. Through the solr admin default query on collection1, I can see all the data have been imported and indexed. the indexed data involved one main table opinion and a related table resorts. I have no problem to do the default search on the fields in the opinion table, but cannot do default search on the fields in the related nested table resorts. ( I have copied all the opinion fields and the resorts related fields into the default text field. )  in solr admin query with collection1,  in q box, type resort_name:Galveston, show expected results,  but type Galveston, show 0 results.

Here is my data-config.xml main content

```
<entity name="opinion" pk="Id" query="select Id, fd1, Resort_id, 
                            fd2, Create_date, Update_date FROM  mydb.opinion" 
                            deltaImportQuery="select * FROM mydb.opinion where Id = '${dih.delta.Id}'" 
                            deltaQuery="select Id FROM mydb.opinion 
                            WHERE Create_date > '${dih.last_index_time}' OR 
                            Update_date > '${dih.last_index_time}'"
                            transformer="RegexTransformer">
            <field column="Id" name="id" />
                                <field column="fd1" name="fd1" />
                                <field column="Resort_id" name="Resort_id" />     
                                <field column="fd2" name="fd2" />                            
        <field column="Create_date" name="Create_date" />                             
                            <field column="Update_date" name="Update_date"/>                          

     <entity name="resort" pk="Id" query="select Id, Resort_name, State_prov, Country from mydb.resorts where Id='${opinion.Resort_id}'"
                        deltaQuery="select Id FROM mydb.resorts WHERE Create_date > '${dih.last_index_time}' OR Update_date > '${dih.last_index_time}'"
                        parentDeltaQuery="select Resort_id from opinion where Resort_Id=${resort.Id}" 
                        transformer="RegexTransformer">
                            <field name="rstid" column="Id" />
                            <field name="Resort_name" column="Resort_name" />
                            <field name="State_prov" column="State_prov" />
                            <field name="Country" column="Country" />
                        </entity> 

                    </entity>
```

I know the default search goes to "text" field and I have copied the related nested fields to the text field in schema.xml. here is the part in schema.xml:

...

```
    <field name="Resort_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
      <field name="State_prov" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
      <field name="Country" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
      <!-- this is for Id of resorts table -->
      <field name="rstid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    ...
    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey> 
    ....
    <copyField source="id" dest="text"/>
       <copyField source="rstid" dest="text"/>
       <copyField source="fd1" dest="text"/>
       <copyField source="fd2" dest="text"/>
       <copyField source="Resort_id" dest="text"/>
       <copyfield source="Create_date" dest="text"/>
       <copyfield source="Update_date" dest="text"/>
       <copyfield source="Resort_name" dest="text"/>
       <copyfield source="State_prov" dest="text"/>
       <copyfield source="Country" type="text"/>

In solrconfig.xml, I added the following part to the installed solrconfig.xml:
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">my-data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
   </requestHandler>   

  I did not modify anything else in the solrconfig.xml, here is the select and query request handler:
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
         will be overridden by parameters in the request
      -->
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">10</int>
       <str name="df">text</str>
     </lst>
    </requestHandler>
     <!-- A request handler that returns indented JSON by default -->
  <requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <str name="wt">json</str>
       <str name="indent">true</str>
       <str name="df">text</str>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

The nested table fields default search is important to my application and I have been stuck on this solr configuration for several days. Any suggestion or help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your solrconfif.xml

Comment: I just added the solrconfig.xml.

Comment: I see you have added only the dataimport requestHandler part of your solrconfig.xml. Can you post the query and the requestHandler you are using.

Comment: I just added the query request handler in.